# Firebase initiliaze without google_services.json file

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, android-library

I want to initialize firebase at runtime. I convert the JSON file to XML on this site -> https://dandar3.github.io/android/google-services-json-to-xml.html

Then I put string in app/res/strings.xml file.
[image]

app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
.....
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}
```

I build my project and the error is here:

> Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
>   Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
>   Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.

What is the problem? Firebase says .that you can delete the google_services.json file from your project.
[image]

Comment: Any update on it ? I am blocked by the release build because of the Crahslytics mapping upload task.

Comment: I coudln't do it without google.services.json.

Comment: On my side I "kind of" succeed to have multiple flavors working without Google-services.json. (using your method)
But I have to deactivate the Chraslytics mapping upload : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/uC8aaDKijhA
It's not fully stable but good enough for now for my usage.